# ¿Cómo calcular la media ponderada en PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Tengo una tabla en PostgreSQL que recoge la semana de cosecha en distintas parcelas y distintas comarcas. Las variables son `comarca`, `semana` y `superficie_cosechada`. Necesito calcular la media ponderada de `semana` para cada comarca en función de la superficie cosechada. Es decir, algo parecido a la operación `suma`(`semana`*`superficie_cosechada)`/`suma(superficie_cosechada)` para todas las semanas de la misma comarca. ¿Qué consulta debería hacer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

me sorprende que quieras la media ponderada de `semana` pero aún así, e imaginándome la tabla que voy a mostrar, y suponiendo unos valores de ejemplo, e incluso aceptando la fórmula que describes, sería hacer esto:

```
CREATE TABLE tabla_cosecha (
  comarca varchar(50),
  semana int,
  superficie_cosechada numeric(10,2)
);

INSERT INTO tabla_cosecha (comarca, semana, superficie_cosechada)
VALUES 
('comarca1', 1, 100),
('comarca1', 2, 150),
('comarca1', 3, 200),
('comarca2', 1, 50),
('comarca2', 2, 75),
('comarca2', 3, 100),
('comarca2', 4, 120),
('comarca2', 5, 150),
('comarca3', 1, 200),
('comarca3', 2, 250),
('comarca3', 3, 300);



SELECT comarca, SUM(semana*superficie_cosechada)/SUM(superficie_cosechada) as media_ponderada_semana
FROM tabla_cosecha
GROUP BY comarca;
```

Entces esta consulta en esta hipotética tabla da esto como resultado, la media ponderada de `semana`

```
comarca  | media_ponderada_semana 
----------+------------------------
 comarca3 |     2.1333333333333333
 comarca1 |     2.2222222222222222
 comarca2 |     3.4949494949494949
(3 rows)
```

A ver si te sirve, si no, detalla mejor la pregunta y revisa tu fórmula. Un saludo.